# Is Android's Visualizer class's handling of media volume inconsistent across different devices?

Tags: android, visualization, volume

I have made a music visualizer app for Android. While developing on my HTC Legend (running Android 2.2), I noticed that setting the "media volume" of the phone had no effect on the output of the Visalizer class, i.e. I always got the full-volume amplitude data of the playing music, regardless of the volume setting, which was great because that's precisely what I want.

I have recently purchased an Asus EEE transformer tablet, running Android 3.2,  and now the user-set volume DOES impact the volume of the data I get back from the Visualiser class.

Does anyone know what the official behaviour should be? I'd hope for volume independence, but the evidence I've seen points to inconsistent behaviour across different devices...
Is this a driver issue, or has the behaviour changed in 3.2?

Thanks!
Nils

Answer (score 0):

Refere this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8277676/874752). I think that you are  not enable equalizer and visualizer for same seesion id.Accroding to me Audio effects need equalizer engine enable for audio modifications settings.Otherwise it gives higher values and it will be affected by media volume also.

Comment: Short summary of what the link said: also set an Equalizer object on the same sessionId, and it should work. Unfortunately, doing this does not fix the issue for me. Perhaps because I'm doing it on sessionID 0 (output mix) instead of a sessionID of a mediaplayer or audiotrack, or maybe this "feature" works differently on my Asus EEE transformer running ICS. Would be cool if there was actual documentation describing the correct/desired behaviour...